# Google Drive API httpRequest download file dialog box

Tags: php, google-api, google-drive-api

I'm new to PHP and I've been using Google Drive PHP API.

This is my code:

```
function downloadFile1($service,$downloadUrl,$client) {

    if ($downloadUrl) {
      $request = new Google_Http_Request($downloadUrl, 'GET', null, null);

      $SignhttpRequest = $client->getAuth()->sign($request);
      $httpRequest = $client->getIo()->makeRequest($SignhttpRequest);

  if ($httpRequest->getResponseHttpCode() == 200) {

    return $httpRequest->getResponseBody();

  } else {
  // An error occurred.
    return null;
  }
 } else {
  // The file doesn't have any content stored on Drive.
   return null;
 }
}
```

So far so good. But I want to get a dialog box to save the file to my computer (When I get the return result). How could I get that?

[If I perform a

```
$content = $httpRequest->getResponseBody();
print_r($content);]
```

I can see the content of the file in the webpage, but I want to download it!]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using PHP to download the file to the server, show the user an anchor on the page that points to the file's [`webContentLink`](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files#webContentLink). Clicking the link will download the file to the user's computer.

Comment: But if I use webContentLink I receive an error: 403 We're sorry, but you do not have access to this page. I want my app to be able to download a provate file to someone without logging in.

Comment: In that case, do what you are already doing but set the Content-Disposition header so that your browser shows the "Save as" dialog: http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-send-content-disposition.php

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I realize I can set the Google Drive file permissions to Public if the user has the link. So in that case the webContentLnk works and the problem is solved. Thanks again and sorry for disturbing you ;-)

Answer (score -1):

Hi All maybe this code will help people with using google drive as a service that can be used with cronjob/cli to upload, delete and download files with unlimited filesize.

Its not finished yet but its a wrapper of the google apiclient.
And can be used to upload, download and delete files.

```
<?php

namespace App\Model\Google;

class Drive
{
public $pixie;

protected $_config;
protected $_client;
protected $_service;

public function __construct(\App\Pixie $pixie)
{
    $this->pixie = $pixie;
    $this->_config = $this->pixie->config->get('googledrive');

    $this->_client = new \Google_Client();
    $this->_client->setClientId($this->_config['clientId']);
    $this->_client->setClientSecret($this->_config['clientSecret']);
    $this->_client->setRedirectUri($this->_config['redirectUri']); //
    $this->_client->addScope($this->_config['scope']); // scope: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive
    $this->_client->setAccessType($this->_config['accessType']); // offline
    $token = $this->_client->refreshToken($this->_config['refreshToken']);

    $this->_service = new \Google_Service_Drive($this->_client);
}

/**
 * UPLOAD FILE
 */
public function uploadFile($filename, $file)
{
    $gdriveFile = new \Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile();
    $gdriveFile->title = $filename;

    $chunkSizeBytes = 1 * 1024 * 1024;

    // Call the API with the media upload, defer so it doesn't immediately return.
    $this->_client->setDefer(true);
    $request = $this->_service->files->insert($gdriveFile);
    $mimeType = 'text/plain';
    // Create a media file upload to represent our upload process.
    $media = new \Google_Http_MediaFileUpload(
      $this->_client,
      $request,
      $mimeType,
      null,
      true,
      $chunkSizeBytes
    );

    $media->setFileSize(filesize($file));

    // Upload the various chunks. $status will be false until the process is
    // complete.
    $status = false;
    $handle = fopen($file, "rb");
    while (!$status && !feof($handle)) {
        $chunk = fread($handle, $chunkSizeBytes);
        $status = $media->nextChunk($chunk);
    }

    // The final value of $status will be the data from the API for the object
    // that has been uploaded.
    $result = false;
    if ($status !== false) {
        $result = $status;
    }

    return $result;
}

/**
 * DOWNLOAD FILE
 */
public function downloadUrl($fileId)
{
    $file = $this->getFile($fileId);

    if ($url = $file->getWebContentLink()) {
        return $url;
    }

    return false;
}

/**
 * GET FILE
 *   $file = $service->files->get($fileId);
 */
public function getFile($fileId)
{
    try {
        return $this->_service->files->get($fileId);
    } catch(\Exception $e) {
        throw new \Exception('Google Drive File Does Not Exist');
    }
}

/**
 * DELETE FILE
 *   $service->files->delete($fileId);
 */
public function deleteFile($fileId)
{
    new \Debug();
}

/**
 * FILE TO TRASH
 *   $service->files->trash($fileId);
 */
public function trashFile($fileId)
{
    new \Debug();
}

/**
 * EMPTY TRASH
 *   $service->files->emptyTrash();
 */
public function emptyTrash()
{
    new \Debug();
}

/**
 * FILE UNTRASH
 *   $service->files->untrash($fileId);
 */
public function untrashFile($fileId)
{
    new \Debug();
}

/**
 * LIST OF FILES
 *   $list = $service->files->listFiles();
 */
public function listOfFiles()
{
    new \Debug();
}
}
```